# When using blitzindex should are the reads the number of times the index was used to read or is that the op stats?

Tags: index-tuning, sp-blitzindex

Im using blitz index to identify some indexing issues.  Im concerned that I am reading the output incorrectly.  In my output, im seeing reads, compared to writes in the usage column, and then im seeing a lot more reads in the op stats column.  Which column tells me how many times the index has been used for returning data?

[image: BlitzIndex output]

Comment: Please tag the database system in question.

Answer (score 0):

The "Usage Stats" column is from [sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

The "Operational Stats" column is from [sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-operational-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

I won't rehash the Books Online documentation for each DMV here, but the short story is that they both measure how many times the index has been used - they just measure it in different ways.